# Add Tag Element using XMLReader and SimpleXML or XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I want to add Tag element <is_active> with CDATA true or false. Because of huge XML file I have to use XMLReader. I am not sure if I should use SimpleXML or XMLWriter for addin Tag Element. 
Here is a code using XMLWriter:

```
<?php

require('xmlreader-iterators.php'); // require XMLReaderIterator library
$xmlInputFile  = 'feed_sample.xml';
$xmlOutputFile = 'output.xml';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlInputFile);

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri($xmlOutputFile);

$iterator = new XMLWritingIteration($writer, $reader);

$writer->startDocument();

foreach ($iterator as $node) {
    $isElement = $node->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT;

    if ($isElement && $node->name === 'offer') {
        $writer->startElement('is_active');
        $writer->text('true');
        if ($node->isEmptyElement) {
            $writer->endElement();
        }
    } else {
        // handle everything else
        $iterator->write();
    }
}

$writer->endDocument();
```

Here is a code using SimpleXML:

```
<?php

$fn = __DIR__ . '/feed_sample.xml';

$tag = 'offer';
$reader = new \XMLReader();

if (!$reader->open($fn)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("Could not open {$fn} with XMLReader");
}


while ($reader->read()) {


    while ($tag === $reader->name) {

        $elem = new \SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());
        $opening_times = (string) $elem->opening_times;
        $opening_times_array = explode('"', $opening_times);
        print_r($opening_times_array);
        $add = $elem->addChild('is_active', 'true');

        $reader->next($tag);
        $elem->asXML('outputSimple.xml');
    }

}
```

And shorter verion XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<offers>
<offer>
    <id><![CDATA[2109]]></id>
    <name><![CDATA[Sleek Frozen Sausages]]></name>
    <category><![CDATA[Sleek]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[Eum aut qui est delectus suscipit aut voluptas quaerat maiores architecto perferendis dolorum tenetur iure nemo omnis laboriosam voluptatem et iste molestias sed voluptas eum facilis aliquam tempora autem aspernatur ipsum corrupti cum corrupti quae dolor modi consequatur provident illo maiores eius aspernatur id nostrum nisi repellat enim a hic unde laboriosam possimus est ipsam qui mollitia nesciunt est culpa voluptatem sit dignissimos quidem facilis dolorem facilis et explicabo ea veniam quis architecto autem occaecati quaerat omnis reprehenderit doloribus labore saepe asperiores a ea possimus dolor necessitatibus numquam doloremque velit fuga ipsam numquam quia omnis voluptas voluptas rerum sint eveniet sit in error quia nemo delectus perferendis asperiores quam quam assumenda reiciendis sunt aut et saepe ea adipisci eum debitis odit similique consectetur nesciunt ducimus maxime sed consequuntur repellendus qui illum vero necessitatibus perferendis cumque optio voluptatibus et quas velit voluptatem tempore est et officiis tempora iusto rerum eum amet a qui corrupti ex nobis laborum eum assumenda velit laboriosam et sed sapiente accusantium officia enim doloremque perspiciatis quos ut rerum molestias ut ut aut omnis vitae placeat voluptas iusto distinctio ea molestias et at et aliquam libero non neque dicta quos numquam est non explicabo ipsa neque dolores rerum.]]></description>
    <price><![CDATA[252.65 EUR]]></price>
    <url><![CDATA[https://example.com/product/2109]]></url>
    <image_url><![CDATA[http://lorempixel.com/640/480]]></image_url>
    <opening_times><![CDATA[{"1":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"2":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"3":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"4":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"5":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"6":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"7":[],"timezone":"Europe/Warsaw"}]]></opening_times>
</offer>
<offer>
    <id><![CDATA[7673]]></id>
    <name><![CDATA[Ergonomic Soft Fish]]></name>
    <category><![CDATA[Rustic]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[Pariatur consectetur autem reiciendis ab ea est fugiat tenetur suscipit ut sit rem accusamus accusamus accusamus veniam commodi omnis quia minus ratione reprehenderit est porro omnis modi et ipsa aut itaque impedit inventore modi nisi nemo commodi nesciunt earum quia sed assumenda nulla quia qui neque laborum vitae nobis dolorem perspiciatis tenetur nisi asperiores eos itaque dolorem sit est nostrum sequi similique doloremque vero id voluptas exercitationem eveniet saepe non impedit aut neque aut sed molestiae aut cum hic consectetur facilis porro atque perspiciatis maiores maiores ut aut enim iste maxime dolores est dolores quaerat dolores error nisi et esse voluptas occaecati nostrum quasi vero porro natus iste molestiae totam culpa vero voluptate porro aut ut iusto non ullam quam aut itaque velit quis maiores nobis officia ut iure voluptatibus iure nihil optio repellendus eum similique eum in excepturi doloremque rerum cumque accusantium fuga sed sed odit vel qui nam eum iure sapiente magni et temporibus quis qui pariatur tempora odit explicabo et mollitia autem nihil autem repellat ut et laudantium ab dolores nisi porro fuga sed laudantium quae delectus debitis quaerat doloremque praesentium quod ullam accusamus architecto earum impedit esse sint sint fugiat nihil itaque ut ut aut provident.]]></description>
    <price><![CDATA[384.12 EUR]]></price>
    <url><![CDATA[https://example.com/product/7673]]></url>
    <image_url><![CDATA[http://lorempixel.com/640/480]]></image_url>
    <opening_times><![CDATA[{"1":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"2":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"3":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"4":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"5":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"6":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"7":[],"timezone":"Europe/Warsaw"}]]></opening_times>
</offer>
</offers>
```

This is my output for XMLWriter:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<offers>
<is_active>true
    <id/>
    <name/>
    <category/>
    <description/>
    <price/>
    <url/>
    <image_url/>
    <opening_times/>
</is_active>
</offers>
```

This is my output for SimpleXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<offer>
    <id><![CDATA[5086]]></id>
    <name><![CDATA[Ergonomic Frozen Fish]]></name>
    <category><![CDATA[Incredible]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[Molestiae et et esse temporibus iure numquam fugiat impedit dolor molestiae neque mollitia doloremque aut minus debitis officia ut alias earum voluptas quas velit consequatur qui aut possimus ut corporis quis aut numquam est sint unde sint aliquam qui qui dolor distinctio accusamus quae eveniet sit et itaque dolorem aut ea quia et repellat delectus quaerat aperiam blanditiis repellat esse architecto inventore delectus enim voluptates non hic amet ut aut aut et quis earum pariatur ut ex eos in sed sit ut quo inventore et quo officia suscipit tempore doloremque rerum iusto aperiam quae quas laboriosam et et quia facere qui facilis magni earum perferendis rerum saepe accusantium dolorem nostrum nam et et sequi nam aliquam et facilis repellendus omnis impedit minus eligendi ipsum et quidem qui corrupti possimus est iusto alias libero illum voluptate vel blanditiis minus dolorem voluptas at eum laborum aut architecto maxime voluptatem et debitis ab enim neque eum aliquid quis officiis quidem molestiae sint est vero voluptas dolores qui commodi aspernatur eius numquam eos voluptatem voluptatem praesentium rerum voluptatibus doloremque labore iste ex cupiditate asperiores tenetur voluptatem dolorem quo aut corrupti omnis iusto mollitia eligendi eum natus repudiandae error porro quisquam eum eligendi aut officiis.]]></description>
    <price><![CDATA[219.57 EUR]]></price>
    <url><![CDATA[https://example.com/product/5086]]></url>
    <image_url><![CDATA[http://lorempixel.com/640/480]]></image_url>
    <opening_times><![CDATA[{"1":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"21:00"}],"2":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"21:00"}],"3":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"21:00"}],"4":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"21:00"}],"5":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"21:00"}],"6":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"21:00"}],"7":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"20:00"}],"timezone":"Europe/Warsaw"}]]></opening_times>
<is_active>true</is_active></offer>
```

As we can see for XMLWriter results replace Tag Name  with Tag name <is_active> what is unwanted, there are no data inside all Tag elements and there is modified only one Tag Element  (I would like to modified all  Tag Names).

In SimpleXML case there are data for each Tag Name and I wrote inside  Tag Name <is_active>, but as response there is Tag Name <is_active> for only one .

XMLWritter: Why there are no data in each element Tag?

XMLWritter: How can I create Tag Name inside . NOT instead

XMLWritter: How can I create Tag Name for all  Tag Names?

SimpleXML: How can I write a code which take into account all Tags  and add inside Tag <is_active>.

I hope it is clear explanation. I will be greatful for any answer.

Thank you very much for interest and your time.

Comment: How big is your input XML file? Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: Something about 2GB weight. I will check how can I made such modification by XSLT. If you have a good sources please share with me. And thank you very much for response!

Comment: One more thing: As you can see in Tag Name <opening_times> there are opening and closeing hours. What I want to do is assign <is_active>true</is_active> when current hour when we run a script is between opening and closeing hours. Can I put such condition in XSLT? What is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a couple of questions at once, I'll try to answer them. Additionally you can find three code examples linked at the very end, that are available if you clone the git repository of
XMLReaderIterator. But now for the questions:

---

> XMLWritter: Why there are no data in each element Tag?

The issue is not with **XMLWriter** here technically. The actual reason is that the **XMLWritingIteration** did not support CDATA at `XMLWritingIteration::write()` in v0.1.10, it is added in v0.1.11. Updating to it should suffice.

Alternative and already earlier, opening the **XMLReader** with [the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-nocdata) makes the writer use text-nodes which it supported already before v0.1.11:

```php
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlInputFile, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

The writing is than having text-nodes instead of CDATA nodes.

---

> XMLWritter: How can I create Tag Name inside . NOT instead

This is also in cooperation with the `XMLWritingIteration::write()` and is a matters of order.

To write inside - not instead of - the ELEMENT (that is the start tag), the parent element has to be written first:

```php
$iterator->write();
```

As this is **XMLWriter** beneath, it writes the opening element. If it is not an empty element, then the new `<is_active>true</is_active>` (or false) can be written:

```
    $iterator->write();
    if ($isElement && $node->name === 'offer' && !$node->isEmptyElement) {
        $writer->writeElement('is_active', 'true');
    }
```

The check for not being an empty element is curcial: Within an empty element, the hierarchy would be broken as there is no pairing END_ELEMENT for it and the `write()` operations within the whole XMLReader iteration would then leave the tag open.

A memory aid could be that there is no place inside an empty element to add an XML child element into it.

Technically it is totally possible to handle empty tags as well, it just needs a bit more care, e.g. adding it as the only children:

```php
    $iterator->write();
    if ($isElement && $node->name === 'offer') {
        $writer->writeElement('is_active', 'true');
    }
    if ($node->isEmptyElement) {
        $writer->fullEndElement();
    }
```

---

> XMLWritter: How can I create Tag Name for all Tag Names?

Assumably this is already solved with the previous point. The output in your question shows that each `<offer>` element was dropped, only the children were written out.

This was caused by not writing out the offer element when found. As in the previous example `$iterator->write()` is always in use, the element is output as well.

Instead of always calling `$iterator->write()`, it is naturally possible to do it conditionally as in your questions example - and when not in use - use **XMLWriter** to create your own output, e.g. if the name of offer element should be changed.

---

> I am not sure if I should use SimpleXML or XMLWriter for addin[g a] Tag Element.

This depends as both can be used. And the *XMLReaderIterators* support this also in a convenient form, so it is easy to compare both approaches with each other.

The project has examples for these scenarios with [pure XMLReader/XMLWriter](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator/blob/master/examples/read-write-cdata.php#L30), with [XMLReader/Writer and DOM](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator/blob/master/examples/read-write-dom.php#L30) and as well as with [XMLReader/Writer and SimpleXML](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator/blob/master/examples/read-write-simplexml.php#L30).